# Why is my_getline() causing a system hang?

Tags: c, arrays, file

This program attempts to save the contents of a text file into a character variable array.  It is then supposed to use my_getline() to print the contents of the character array.  I've tested and see that the contents are in fact getting saved into  `char *text` but I can't figure out how to print the contents of `char *text` using my_getline().  my_getline is a function we wrote in class that I need to use in this program.  When I attempt to call it in the way that was taught, it `1` is printed to terminal but then the terminal just waits and nothing else is printed.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Also, let me know if I'm missing any information that would help.

```
/*   Include the standard input/output and string libraries             */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*   Define the maximum lines allowed in an input text and NEWLINE for getline funct.   */
#define MAXPATTERN 15
#define MAXFILENAMELENGTH 15
#define NEWLINE '\n'

/*   function prototypes                                */
void my_getline(char text[]);
int find_string(char text[], char pattern[], int length_text, int length_pattern);

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   long lSize;
   char *text;
   char fileName[MAXFILENAMELENGTH], pattern[MAXPATTERN];
   char c;
   int length_text, length_pattern, j, lineNumber = 1;

   printf("Enter file name: ");
   scanf("%s", fileName);

   fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("fopen failed.\n");
      return(-1);
   }

   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell(fp);
   rewind(fp);

/*   allocate memory for all of text file                       */
   text = calloc(1, lSize + 2);
   if(!text)
   {
      fclose(fp);
      fputs("memory allocs fails", stderr);
      exit(1);
   }

/*   copy the file into text                                */
   if(1 != fread(text, lSize, 1, fp))
   {
      fclose(fp);
      free(text);
      fputs("Entire read fails", stderr);
      exit(1);
   }
   text[lSize + 1] = '\0';

   printf("%s has been copied.\n", fileName);

   rewind(fp);
   printf("%d  ", lineNumber);
   for (j = 0; (j = getchar()) != '\0'; j++)
   {
      my_getline(text);
      printf("%d %s\n", j+1, text);      
   }


   printf("Enter the pattern you would like to search for: ");
   scanf("%s", pattern);
   printf("\nYou have chosen to search for: %s\n", pattern);

   fclose(fp);
   free(text);
   return(0);
}

void my_getline(char text[])
{
   int i = 0;
   while ((text[i] = getchar()) != NEWLINE)
      ++i;
   text[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You've already copied the contents of the file to `text`.  When you call `my_getline`, is it your intent to overwrite it with data coming from `stdin`?  Use of `getchar` seems wrong.

Comment: Truth be told, the entirety of the my_getline function confuses me.  It was my understanding that it prints the text contained in `*text` one line at a time, but I see it doesn't return anything so I'm not sure what it's really doing.  Our professor wrote it with us in class and we were told we must use it on this assignment.  Can you explain to me what's going on with it and why it's not optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is causing a system hang because you're calling [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/)(), which returns the next character from the standard input. Is this really what you want?

At this point, your program is expecting input from the user. Try typing in the console windows and pressing  to see it coming back from the "hang"

Comment: You are right, the hang is caused by getchar().  When I type into the console, it outputs three numbers plus the word (but takes off the first letter of the word).  I realize that this isn't what I want but my professor made it seem like we weren't really meant to mess with the my_getline function when writing this program.  Does this mean I need to try a completely different approach?

Comment: my_getline() functions appears to be getting characters from the console and storing them in the _text_ array. From my understanding, it is very unlikely that your task is to print to the console using this function.

Comment: You are correct.  I think it was expected that I would redirect the text file to the program through the console, in which case that function would have worked.  Instead, I am choosing to access the file through the program itself.  I have scrapped my_getline() completely and have chosen to iterate through the character array one character at a time using a normal for-loop.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely causing an infinite loop because you are not checking whether you have reached EOF.

```
void my_getline(char text[])
{
   int i = 0;
   int c;
   while ( (c = getchar()) != NEWLINE && c != EOF )
      text[i++] = c;
   text[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to resemble yours but the problem isn't solved.  I realize now that it isn't an infinite loop, but rather it prints 1 and the system just waits there.

Comment: You said 8print the contents of `char *text` using `my_getline()`.*  That is a bit misleading. The name is 'get' and you are expecting it to 'print'. Please clarify what your intentions are.

Comment: My intentions are to print the contents of char *text one line at a time through calls to my_getline().  We have to use my_getline() in the program, but I don't understand how it would print one line at at a time if it doesn't even return anything.  I'm confused about it's usage.

Comment: @PatMulvihill, it will be useful to get some clarification from your instructor about the purpose of that function.